# How to emit socketio message outside event handler

Tags: flask, socket.io, celery, flask-socketio

I'm trying to emit a message from a celery task. However the emit message doesn't reach the client, even when trying to broadcast:

```
@celery.task(bind=True)
def search_pdf(self, path, keyword, room):#, url):
    socketio.emit('message', {'msg': 'results' + ':' + 'message from a celery'}, namespace='/chat', broadcast=True)
    socketio.emit('message', {'msg': 'results' + ':' + 'message from a celery'}, broadcast=True)
```

Upon debugging it seems that the emit doesn't reach the client whenever I call it outside the socketio event handler, so there must be something I misunderstand about `flask-socketio`, can someone enlighten me?

For reference this is my init call within my `create_app()` function:

```
socketio.init_app(app, async_mode='eventlet', message_queue=app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'])
```

And this is my celery app function:

```
def create_celery_app(app=None):
    """
    Create a new Celery object and tie together the Celery config to the app's
    config. Wrap all tasks in the context of the application.

    :param app: Flask app
    :return: Celery app
    """
    app = app or create_app()
    # app.app_context().push()

    celery = Celery(app.import_name, broker=app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'],
                    include=CELERY_TASK_LIST)
    celery.conf.update(app.config)
    TaskBase = celery.Task

    class ContextTask(TaskBase):
        abstract = True

        def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            with app.app_context():
                return TaskBase.__call__(self, *args, **kwargs)

    celery.Task = ContextTask
    return celery
```

- I'm using Flask with a gunicorn server with the `eventlet` worker class for flask-socketio.
- I'm also using docker-compose with celery and redis containers as the task queue
- And using Miguel Grinberg's [example socketio chat app](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-SocketIO-Chat) which works fine

Comment: Are you also using the eventlet async mode when you create your app on the Celery side? That should normally not be based on eventlet, unless the whole Celery process runs on eventlet.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up no I'm not. I've removed `async_mode` from `init_app` but still no luck unfortunately. I think my issue is in my `tasks.py` I'm importing `socketio` as `socketio = SocketIO()` however this is before init_app is called. Should I be importing `socketio.init_app(app, message_queue=app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'])` instead? And how could I do that if it's within my `create_app` function?

Comment: Try passing `async_mode='threading'` on the Celery worker, while having `async_mode='eventlet'` on the server process.